# log4j2.configurationFile comma separated values not getting picked up

Tags: log4j2

Have configured **log4j2.component.properties** file with below system property.

log4j2.configurationFile=log4j2.xml,../config/log4j2.xml,../log/log4j2.xml

However system finds the log4j2.xml file only when it is placed in the current directory. If it is placed either in /config or /log directory, it is unable to find the file.

Could someone suggest what is going wrong here?

Comment: Try composing absolute (full) names, e.g.: `/Users/Srivignesh/someproj/log/log4j2.xml`

Comment: Looks like log4j2.component.properties file itself is not being picked up by the system. I am using log4j 2.9.1 version.